# Charger not charging phone at advertised power, why?

Tags: power

First of all I understand there are so many variables so I'm going to try to be as explicit as possible:

- I have various chargers which state they can deliver 3A @ 5V
- I have an iPhone 12 Pro Max (I am not sure what is the default expected charging voltage, 5V maybe?)
- I am using the charger shown below which has 2 types of slots: 1 type (the 3x green slots) with 3.1A and 1 other type (the 1x orange slot) with QuickCharge 3
- I am using a charging cable with 2.4A max capability with visual display of charging power (it shows me the watts)

Now:

- if I plug the cable in the green slots (with 3.1A) the display shows approx 5W which I assume is 1A @ 5V
- if I plug the cable in the orange slot (QuickCharge 3) the display shows approx 12W which I assume is 2.4A @ 5V

Why is this happening? More specifically, why don't I have 12W/2.4A charging with the green slots too? I also tried multiple chargers which advertise themselves as 2-3A charging but all I get is the slow 5W charging.

[image: output info]

[image: output slots]

Comment: Temperature? Smart charging? The phone normally only takes what it wants.

Comment: The chemical reaction in the battery must be limited, otherwise it will get hot enough to damage the structural parts of the battery which separate the chemicals (if they're not separated, they react quickly and without sending electrons through wires and just make heat, and possibly an explosion). To prevent overheat, batteries need to limit what they take in. The difference in protocols has to do with where the limiting mechanism lives.

Comment: that's not a charger ... it is a power supply ... the charger is built into the phone

Comment: Temperature is not the culprit. I'm changing the ports in a matter of seconds to test them

Comment: are you asking why two different charge standards charge at different rates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Charge is a standard for chargers and power supplies to negotiate and provide voltages greater than 5V.  In addition, when the power supply is providing the control of the voltage or amperage, the charger can potentially bypass some of its miniaturized, internal control circuitry that was built around the dumb 5V coming in; there's a difference between 5V, and 5V with the potential to command it down to less than 4V within some time per a standard.

Your assumption that the 5W is 1A @5V is probably about right. Your assumption that 12W is 2.4A@5V is probably wrong; QuickCharge 3 goes up to a potential of 22V (although yours may not; manufacturers probably aim a bit lower to make sure they are in spec).

You can read more about voltages and QuickCharge on the wikipedia article and its cited sources https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge

Comment: Ok, I understand the QuickCharge part, but why do the non-QC ports only charge at 5W/1A even though they are capable of more? Who/what is limiting the charge to 5W?

Comment: 5V is the USB standard. The charger's non QC ports stick inside 5V even if wattage is lowered for it. Without communication, power supply does not know that the thing downstream can take more, so it assumes that 5V is safe, and uses that. Charging standards like QuickCharge and PD establish how communication is supposed to be done- a language of sorts. Most devices can't talk to one another, so wiring standards tried to only let the appropriate stuff connect by using different connectors all over - the wall outlet carries over 100V so it is given a connector that signifies that.

Answer (score 0):

Phone charging is a lot more complicated than it appears. USB devices negotiate digitally to adjust limits for the current and supply voltage. I believe USB 3.0 cables even include a digital IC.

Furthermore, electrically a 5V 3A source is really just a 5V source that can supply **up to** 3A. The current is determined by the load. If the load only consumes 2.4A, then that is what will flow.

One of the ports on your charger appears to support the protocols and circuitry required for "quick charge", whereas the others are "dumber" and don't support that mode of operation.

Comment: Since on one of the ports it consumes 2.4A then it's obvious the load attempts to consume at least 2.4A, but the other ports don't supply that current even though they can do it

Comment: The USB standard likely does not permit the device to draw more than 1A without negotiation.